# Identify story about a fantasy world threatened by aliens

Tags: story-identification, aliens, magic, young-adult

Children's / YA book, don't remember too much about it.
Main character is a wizard/apprentice? 
Prophecy of imminent destruction, quest to prevent it.
Other fantasy races: trolls, living in underground caverns.
Danger turns out to be alien spaceship which begins to harvest world for resources, by building a series of signal fires manage to communicate the presence of intelligent life.

[Teranon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/12450/teranon) adds: The dragon(s?) in the story spoke with certain parts of the sentences replaced with synonyms with slashes (for example: great/wonderful/fantastic). Also the main characters were a father son team, with the son apprenticed to the wizard father.
I also think they made the signals in geometric shapes (circle, triangle, etc).

Comment: Not that I know anything about the story, but does it mean the alien are actually benevolent? I mean they accidentally mine the world thinking it doesn't has any intelligent live and they stop when they get the message from the heroes?

Comment: Yes, I don't actually remember if there was much detail given about the aliens, may have actually been an AI mining ship - anyway they stopped/left once the heroes got their attention, I think perhaps they used the lights to signal some sort of mathematical pattern?

Comment: Er... I know it's late to ask any of the people involved, but what evidence do we have that @Teranon is talking about the same book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tom McGowan's *[Age of Magic](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/799417.The_Magical_Fellowship)* trilogy, if anyone still cares.

> In 3000 B.C., Lithim, an apprentice magician, and his father set out to unite the warring races of wizards, humans, Little People, and dragons in an effort to save the earth from being destroyed by creatures from beyond the sky.

Comment: We do care! Late answers are fine here :-) But could you add some more details about this series and why it matches the description given in the question?